# Gradle-Build: Cannot convert the provided notation to a File or URI

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

When building with Gradle in IntelliJ with the follwoing gradle.build file:

```
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jdom/jdom
    compile (
            [group: 'org.jdom', name: 'jdom', version: '2.0.0'],
            [group: 'org.controlsfx', name: 'controlsfx', version: '8.40.14'],
            [group: 'net.java.openjfx.backport', name: 'openjfx-78-backport-compat', version: '1.8.0.1']
    )
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'de.to.main.class.itv.Main'
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
9:44:43 PM: Executing task 'build'...

Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:compileJava
:processResources
:classes
:jar FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not copy MANIFEST.MF to 'C:\Users\pre name\Java\Uni\SWP\ITV\build\tmp\jar\MANIFEST.MF'.
> Cannot convert the provided notation to a File or URI: [ZIP 'D:\Development\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jdom\jdom\2.0.0\e03447aa5a53e7ee9f0ebb9da64c5c178900173d\jdom-2.0.0.jar', ZIP 'D:\Development\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.controlsfx\controlsfx\8.40.14\7338f13794b82c77ea152803df56a15d376c3b0e\controlsfx-8.40.14.jar', ZIP 'D:\Development\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.openjfx.backport\openjfx-78-backport-compat\1.8.0.1\7cb8f4c47f25736b099d0db2a0c518e909ed6e4d\openjfx-78-backport-compat-1.8.0.1.jar'].
  The following types/formats are supported:
    - A String or CharSequence path, for example 'src/main/java' or '/usr/include'.
    - A String or CharSequence URI, for example 'file:/usr/include'.
    - A File instance.
    - A Path instance.
    - A URI or URL instance.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED in 1s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
Cannot convert the provided notation to a File or URI: [ZIP 'D:\Development\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jdom\jdom\2.0.0\e03447aa5a53e7ee9f0ebb9da64c5c178900173d\jdom-2.0.0.jar', ZIP 'D:\Development\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.controlsfx\controlsfx\8.40.14\7338f13794b82c77ea152803df56a15d376c3b0e\controlsfx-8.40.14.jar', ZIP 'D:\Development\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.openjfx.backport\openjfx-78-backport-compat\1.8.0.1\7cb8f4c47f25736b099d0db2a0c518e909ed6e4d\openjfx-78-backport-compat-1.8.0.1.jar'].
The following types/formats are supported:
  - A String or CharSequence path, for example 'src/main/java' or '/usr/include'.
  - A String or CharSequence URI, for example 'file:/usr/include'.
  - A File instance.
  - A Path instance.
  - A URI or URL instance.
9:44:44 PM: Task execution finished 'build'.
```

I guessed it would be a whitspace error in the path, but after changing the service directory path to one without whitspaces, the error keeps to be the same.

The goal is to build a jar of the project including the external dependencys.
The question is, what is wrong with the provided annotation?

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace, and what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @mkobit updated the Question. I am trying to build a jar of the project including the external dependencys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are running into method scoping issues here.

In your block here:

```groovy
jar {
  manifest {
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'de.to.main.class.itv.Main'
  }
}
```

You are first calling the [`manifest(Action<? super Manifest> configureAction)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/jvm/tasks/Jar.html#manifest-org.gradle.api.Action-) method in the `jar` task. Inside of that body, you are calling [`from(Object... mergePath)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/java/archives/Manifest.html#from-java.lang.Object...-) on the `Manifest` type.

> Specifies other manifests to be merged into this manifest.

The method name `from` on `Manifest` shadows the various `from` methods that come from [`AbstractCopyTask`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/AbstractCopyTask.html) (which [`Jar`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/jvm/tasks/Jar.html) inherits from).

What you should be doing if you want to configure the things bundle with the artifact is to call the `from` on the task type. Just move the `from` outside of that `manifest` and you should see a clearer message or things will work out.

```groovy
jar {
  from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
  manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'de.to.main.class.itv.Main'
  }
}
```

Comment: Now i get a follow up error:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 67 more

Comment: @Niels in what? In running the application? I am able to run your main build with `./gradlew jar` after the changes to the `from` call, so it is probably in the specifics in how you package your application.

Comment: In running the resulting jar file after gradle build.